# Set tz to datetime instance having only tzname value ("EDT", "CDT", ...)

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I've got tz names in format: "EDT", "CDT".

Is it possible to set timezone to datetime instance with such tz names?

Comment: The short answer is no.  It cannot be done.  The duplicate I linked to explains why, in the first part of my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

> On many Unix systems (including *BSD, Linux, Solaris, and Darwin), it
>   is more convenient to use the system’s zoneinfo (tzfile(5)) database
>   to specify the timezone rules. To do this, set the TZ environment
>   variable to the path of the required timezone datafile, relative to
>   the root of the systems ‘zoneinfo’ timezone database, usually located
>   at /usr/share/zoneinfo. For example, 'US/Eastern',
>   'Australia/Melbourne', 'Egypt' or 'Europe/Amsterdam'.

```
>>> os.environ['TZ'] = 'US/Eastern'
>>> time.tzset()
>>> time.tzname
('EST', 'EDT')
>>> os.environ['TZ'] = 'Egypt'
>>> time.tzset()
>>> time.tzname
('EET', 'EEST')
```

It work fine with valid timezone strings too

Comment: Unfortunately it's not about my system.
That are the values I receive in JSON data from scraper. I have two separate fields  - datetime and tz in format I defined upper. And I need to somehow to apply tz to datetime.
I know that 'America/Chicago' == 'CDT'. If I have 'America/Chicago' string - I can make tz easily. But I have only 'CDT' string - and I can't find out how to create tz from that.

Comment: You could try creatr datetime object from string using strptime

Comment: I have 2  values;

`tstamp = 15051384000`
`tzname = 'CDT'`

`import datetime as dt`

`my_time = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(tstamp)`

How to apply tz to "my_time" with given "tz_name"?

Comment: Build string first, add timezone to it and parse string than. It might do the trick